# Is there any solution for unicode numeric symbols conversion to actual characters

Tags: php, unicode, decode

I am about to pull my hairs on this issue. If some one has any solution. 
I have an html string

```
$html = '<div id="main">What is going on </div><div>&#1740;&#1729;&#1575;&#1722; 
&#1578;&#1608; &#1705;&#1608;&#1574;&#1740; &#1729</div>
<span>Some More Text &lt;good&gt;</span>;
```

This is the mixed html string having html entities + english characters + numeric symbols of unicode characters.
I want to convert only the numeric symbols of unicode characters to actual unicode character values. There is also user formatting that I do not want to lose.

I want the following output

```
$html = '<div id="main">What is going on </div><div>‘۔سلطان محمود نے گاڑی روکتے ہوئے</div>
<span>Some More Text &lt;good&gt;</span>;
```

I have used the

```
html_entity_decode($html, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
```

but this also converts the `&lt;` to `<` and `&gt;` to `>` that I do not want.

Any Other solution??

Note: I am not asking that unicode characters are not being shown correctly on my webpage, they are shown well. because the webpage renders the numeric symbols and shows as real unicode characters. But I want the actaul unicode characters at the back of the webpage too.

Comment: What would your expected output look like ?

Comment: Can you provie full list of exceptions?

Comment: @sectus I want to convert only the numeric symbols to real unicode characters all others are in exception list.

Comment: I suggest you to register in stackoverflow. You have earned some reputation points and 5 bronze badges already. It would be pity to lose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using preg_preplace_callback with html_entity_decode as callback.

```
$decode_single_entity = function ($matches) {
    return html_entity_decode($matches[0], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
};
$string = preg_replace_callback('/&#\d+;/', $decode_single_entity, $html);
```

Comment: you should change the wording, so this becomes an answer instead of question.

Comment: but will it not be so much time consuming. I mean if there are 10,000 entities, so 10,000 calls to function??

Comment: Yes, it will. Decoding your $html repeated 100 000 times (about 16 MB) took about 9 seconds with plain html_entity_decode and almost 40 seconds with my preg_replace_callback approach. So it is about 4 times slower. Nothing is for free.